# Need to press button twice to update variable in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide, handles

I have the following code as part of my MATLAB GUI code:

```
k = waitforbuttonpress;
if k==0               
   if strcmp(get(handles.YESNO,'String'),'Y')

        hint = 1;
    else
        hint = 0;
    end                
else
    hint = 0;
end
```

I wait for the user to press one of the two YES or NO buttons. Inside each of these callbacks I update the variable `handles.YESNO` as `set(handles.YESNO,'String','Y');` or `set(handles.YESNO,'String','N');` respectively.

When I execute my MATLAB GUI, I have to press the YES button twice for the value to take into effect. Any tips/hints to overcome this issue?

Comment: This is what I have in my YES Callback..

function YES_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
set(handles.YESNO,'String','Y');
guidata(hObject,handles)

Comment: [Use the debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the waitforbuttonpress mask your callback.
Instead, block your executation with uiwait that waits for your figure to close or to uiresume called by the buttons callbacks.

Comment: I did not completely understand what you mean, but when I use the debugger and put breakpoints it works fine. But it does not in actual runtime. Probably "... mask your callback" is whats happening (if that is a thing). 

So uiwait is called to wait for user input and uiresume should be put inside the callbacks?